# where should i link my custom post type taxonomies?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm a newbie and trying to create my own Wordpress Theme. I have created Custom Post Types named 'Works' and a Taxonomy named 'Categories' (with tags as "Custom CMS", "Wordpress" ect)

I want each work to dislay his categories, and to link to a page with all simular Works.

This is my code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'categories' );
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo $term->name;
 }
```

This works ok, but now i'm baffled:

1. How, and where should i link each taxonomy?
2. What's the proper template name, and code?

i appreciate your help and time,
Giannis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some guide to your query.

1. How, and where should i link each taxonomy?

   Answer: It will link to specific taxonomy page.
2. What's the proper template name, and code?

   Answer: The template hierarchy is explained here [Wordpress Taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/)

To have taxonomy link on anchor tag inside your loop:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, and thanks for your reply - the problem is that i've read the Wordpress document on that, and it doesnt say how should i link to that page. I print the taxonomy title, but not the taxonomy link - and since english is not my native language, the taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php is not clear to me: {taxonomy}, on my case, is "categories"?

Comment: @Giannis Yes, for you its a "category".
You can link the by, echo get_term_link( $term )

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried replacing my code to `echo "<a href='$term->slug'>$term->name</a>";` and it did not work, i will try `echo get_term_link( $term )` and will let you know how it went

Comment: Please refer to the answer above, i have edited it for you.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, your code worked out perfectly. My main problem is that i used a plugin to create my Custom Pages, and the taxonomy was not set properly - and thats why i had all this errors. Im marking your reply as a checked solution, and i'm closing this question. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Giannis It feels great to help around. Thank you.